# Why can't I use ROUND on a bigger Excel formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to round the following working formula to 2 digits:

```
=(H5-G5)*100/G5
```

My attempt is:

```
=ROUND(((H5-G5)*100/G5),2)
```

without luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the issue. For some reason my Excel is set up to use ";" instead of "," as separator for formulas.

> =ROUND(((H5-G5)*100/G5);2)

instead of

> =ROUND(((H5-G5)*100/G5),2)

works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The values in **H5** and **G5** must be such that the rounding will produce a visible result.

For example, in **G1** enter:  `=(H5-G5)*100/G5` and in **H1** enter:  `=ROUND((H5-G5)*100/G5,2)`

For sample values *97* and *83*:

[image]

If we had chosen **H5** to be *10* and **G5** to be *5*, then the rounding would produce no visible results.